# malformed array literal: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I'm using a postgres function that loops another function which uses dblink to commit updates to my db.

Here is a part from the "inner" function:

```
    selectedIds := array(select id from items where id2 is null and id > latestItemId order by id asc  limit _limit);
highestItemId := (select max(x) from unnest(selectedIds) x);
updatedItemCount := array_length(selectedIds, 1);
raise notice 'updatedItemCount %', updatedItemCount;
raise notice 'SelectedItemiDs %', selectedIds;

PERFORM dblink_connect('dblink_trans','dbname=notified-local port=5432 user=postgres');
PERFORM dblink('dblink_trans','update items set id2 = id where id = any(' || selectedIds || ')');
PERFORM dblink('dblink_trans','COMMIT;');
PERFORM dblink_disconnect('dblink_trans');
```

My raise notice on selectedIds looks like this: {23,60,65,66,588,968,1049,1198,1236,1356,1358,1359,1360,1364,1365,1366}

and then i get the error in the title when i'm trying to do the dblink update.

The error says that i should have { as a start of my array and from what i can see in the raise notice that is exactly what i have?

Comment: `{}` is for an array as a string literal. In that case it must be in quotes. Your query amounts to `any({1,2,3,...})` which is not valid; it must either be `any(array[1,2,3,...])` or `any('{1,2,3,...}')`

Comment: @404 when i grab the selectedIds i set the array(select....) doesn't that make it into a valid array? And in case i want to do your last example any('{1,2,3}') how do i escape ' so that i can type that into my dblink query? :)

Comment: tried to do this  

any(''' || selectedIds || ''') 

but that didn't work either :(

Comment: Do this: `any(''' || selectedIds::TEXT || ''')`

Answer (score 1):

Your array literal is missing the single quotes. It is best to use `format` to avoid SQL injection problems:

```
PERFORM dblink('dblink_trans',
               format('update items set id2 = id where id = any(%L)',
                      selectedIds)
              );
```